# Cell doesn't remain colored

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a pixel art maker using jQuery and added functionality to reenter the default 'draw' mode after using 'erase' mode. It works to color multiple cells, but my code to color a single cell isn't working.

If you:

1. Use 'fill' button to fill grid with color
2. Click 'erase' and erase one cell
3. Click 'draw' and try to color the erased cell

The cell fills with color for a split second then is cleared again. 
However, if you simply click draw mode after the page loads and click a cell, it is colored normally.

Here's the code I used (part of another function). To view my full code/see how it works, you can view my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VQRrgQ).

```
  $('td').click(function() {
  // Adds chosen color to cell upon a click event. Selector 'this' refers to cell (with class 'Cell') being clicked. Variable 'color' is defined here rather than globally so JS checks whether a new color has been picked before each mousedown event
    const color = $('.color-picker').val();
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
  });
```

Comment: Fixed with .off()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disconnect things such as

```
$(pixelCanvas).on('click', 'td', function() {
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

when the `erase` tool is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the mode changes, you're adding listeners and never removing the previous ones - so, for example, you could mousedown, triggering the drawing of a box, followed immediately by the calling of the handler that erases the box.

You should try to refactor your code so that previous listeners get removed when the mode changes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var color=""; 
var type=0;
$(function()
{
 $("tr td").css({"width":"100px","cursor":"pointer"}); 
 
});
$("document").ready(function()
{
 $("td").click( function()
    {
  if(type==1)
   $(this).css("background-color","");
  else if(type==2)
   $(this).css("background-color",color);
 });
 
 $("#txtColor").click( function()
    {
  setP();
 });
 
 $("#txtColor").change( function()
 {
  color=$(this).val();
  setP();
 });
 $("#btnR").click( function()
    {
  type=1;
  setP();
 });
 $("#btnD").click( function()
    {
  type=2;
  setP();
 });
 
});
function setP()
{
 var text="";
 if(color.length>0)
  text+="Current Select Color : "+color;
 else
  text+="Select Color";
 
 text+="<br>";
 
 if(type==1)
  text+="Select Earase";
 else if(type==2) 
  text+="Select Draw";
  
  
 $("p").html(text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">
<p></p>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>00 click here</td>
        <td>01 click here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10 click here</td>
        <td>11 click here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>20 click here</td>
        <td>21 click here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>30 click here</td>
        <td>31 click here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>40 click here</td>
        <td>41 click here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>50 click here</td>
        <td>51 click here</td>
    </tr>
</table>


 <input id="txtColor" type="color">
    <input id="btnR" type="button" value="earase">
    <input id="btnD" type="button" value="draw">

</div>
```